# Execute Controller Method During window.onbeforeunload event

Tags: javascript-remoting

I have a visualforce page that runs calculations and stores them in an sObject as "temporary" until a user clicks a Save button, which removes the temporary flag.  This was done because the calculations take longer than the max CPU time limit available, and a batch process does the calculations while the page polls for results to be completed.

My issue is that when a user doesn't save the records, and navigates away from the page (clicks any link, closes the window, etc), I want to delete the temporary records.

I've tried doing JS Remoting like this, but it didn't work:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    // delete the temporary records.
    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.MyController.deleteTemporaryRecords}','{!reportId}',handleResult);
    console.log('deleting temporary records. {!reportId}');
}
```

I've also tried the different syntax for JS Remoting like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    // delete the temporary records.
    MyController.deleteTemporaryRecords('{!reportId}',handleResult);
    console.log('deleting temporary records. {!reportId}');
}
```

I've also tried using an actionFunction inside the apex:Form

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:actionFunction name="deleteTemporaryRecords" action="{!deleteTemporaryRecords}"/>
</apex:form>

window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    deleteTemporaryRecords();
};
```

I also tried calling a @future method from my controller method so that the delete happens asynchronously, but that hasn't worked either.

Has anyone been able to successfully run a controller method during window.onbeforeunload or window.onunload events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255649/window-onbeforeunload-not-working), I suggest you update your `onbeforeunload` to `return null;` like so:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    // delete the temporary records.
    MyController.deleteTemporaryRecords('{!reportId}',handleResult);
    console.log('deleting temporary records. {!reportId}');
    return null;
}
```

That said, I would be very wary of this approach.  Clients will not necessarily fire this event, so you shouldn't depend on it to delete the temporary records.  Instead, I would probably run a regular scheduled job to delete temporary records that were created `> x` minutes or hours ago.

Comment: Wow, simple oversight on my part for returning null.  Thanks :D.  As for the batch, I didn't want a user's temporary records to get deleted while they might still have the page open.  I thought about doing a scheduled batch to run every 15 minutes or so, that would delete all temp records with LastModifiedDate > some configurable number of minutes in the past.  I may add a timeout function to the page that would delete the records after a certain time interval, then refresh the page.  That way, any kind of navigation from the page, or no activity at all would both fire the the same method.